# Symfony2, Inheritance in same namespace but different file

Tags: symfony, inheritance, namespaces

Since a week I'm in love with Symfony2. I've a feedbackmessagebundle: `src/Erwine/FeedBackMessageBundle` .

I put some custom classes from another project in:  `src/Erwine/FeedBackMessageBundle/FeedBackMessage`.

All classes has the same namespace: `Erwine\FeedBackMessageBundle\FeedBackMessage`.

I've several implementations in different files. Let's say:
- `FeedBackMessageClassOne`
- `FeedBackMessageClassTwo`
- `FeedBackMessageClassThree`

The first one lives *in his own file*. If Two extends from One I got a failure. I've tried `use...` etc.

Two and Three lives as twins in the same file. If Three inherits from Two, it works.
An instance of One in the controller is no problem.

It seems to me, the inheritance of classes in the same namespace in different files doesn't work. No, no, no, course not, I do something wrong. Isn't it? But what? Is it autoloading in Symfony2 for custom classes?

I am using composer for the dependencies.

**UPDATE**
Here is my implementation:

```
<?php  

namespace Erwine\FeedBackMessageBundle\FeedBackMessage;

class FeedBackMessageHandlerImpl extends FeedBackMessageHandlerImplTwee
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        //var_dump('constructed');
        //parent::__construct();
    }

    //public function getFeedBackMessageGeneralOverride(){};
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you get? I'll update my answer if it's not already solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your autoloading is set up correctly, it should just be something like this:

Folder structure:

```
src/
    Erwine/
        FeedBackMessageBundle/
            FeedBackMessage/
                FeedBackMessageClassOne.php
                FeedBackMessageClassTwo.php
                FeedBackMessageClassThree.php
```

**FeedBackMessageClassOne.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Erwine\FeedBackMessageBundle\FeedBackMessage;

class FeedBackMessageClassOne 
{
    // Contents of class...
}
```

**FeedBackMessageClassTwo.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Erwine\FeedBackMessageBundle\FeedBackMessage;

class FeedBackMessageClassTwo extends FeedBackMessageClassOne 
{
    // Contents of class...
}
```

You shouldn't need a `use` statement for the extend in the second file as the file resides in the same namespace, therefore by defining the same namespace in the second class, you are able to use the first class without the use statement.

Make sure that your autoloading is set up properly.

**It's important that you keep every class in a separate file, and also that you name the files the same as the classes.**

This is because Symfony uses PSR-0 by default if you're using the composer autoloader. [Go here to read more about PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)

Comment: I removed 'FeedBackMessageThree' from the file. It's now the same as you described. I will search for knowledge about the autoloading. Should I point to the namespace?

Comment: Well, I can give you a hand with that. If you update your question and include the current source code that'd help a lot. Also, could you tell me the exact names of the files involved?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Here is my implementation: ```<?php
namespace Erwine\FeedBackMessageBundle\FeedBackMessage;

class FeedBackMessageHandlerImpl extends FeedBackMessageHandlerImplTwee
{


    public function __construct() {
    //var_dump('constructed');
    //parent::__construct();
    }

    //public function getFeedBackMessageGeneralOverride(){};
    
}```

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Just to confirm then, is that file called `FeedBackMessageHandlerImpl.php`? And is the file that `FeedBackMessageHandlerImplTwee` is in called `FeedBackMessageHandlerImplTwee.php`?

Comment: I get a 500 error. I am able to create instances of them separate in the controller.

Comment: Okay, do you get an error message with that? If not could you make sure you're using the dev front-controller. To do that you'd do something like this: `http://example.domain/app_dev.php/path/parts` instead of `http://example.domain/path/parts`. Could you also show the code from where you're trying to actually use this class (i.e. the controller).

Comment: I changed: `domain/Symfony/web/feedbackmessage` to `domain/Symfony/app_dev.php/feedbackmessage`. Result: 404, not found. For app.php the same. This is working: `/Symfony/web/app_dev.php`. I get an exception: `No route found for "GET /"`

Comment: If you're getting that error then you've not set up a route to go to your controller. [You should take a look at this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

Comment: I changed: `domain/Symfony/web/feedbackmessage` to `domain/Symfony/app_dev.php/feedbackmessage`. It's working. I get an Exception: ClassNotFound. I've removed already the, I've to clear the dev cache, I think so.

Comment: Seer! It's working now! Thanks for helping and your patience! The solution is: clear cache dev. Separate the classes in different files. I'm glad with it!

Comment: Hooray :), glad to hear it. Sorry for the late reply, had to sleep haha. If you think you're happy with my answer could you mark it as the correct one please?